# How to use Converters in my Net.Maui Toolkit.Popup?

Tags: popup, converters, maui

I am using converters in my regular pages.

I add Currencies in the VM

```
public ObservableCollection<Currency> Currencies { get; set; } = new();
....
```

and then I use them in a picker like so:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <model:CountryPickerConverter x:Key="CountryPickerConverter" />
            <model:CurrencyPickerConverter x:Key="CurrencyPickerConverter" />
            <toolkit:IsNotEqualConverter x:Key="IsNotEqualConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and then

```
<Picker
    Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.SelectCurrency}"
    ItemsSource ="{Binding Currencies}"
    ItemDisplayBinding ="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource CurrencyPickerConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ..........
</Picker>
```

It works. But now I need to do the same thing in my toolkit:Popup object.

I am not able to write this section:

```
<toolkit:Popup.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <model:CurrencyPickerConverter x:Key="CurrencyPickerConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

or something similar.

I did not find any example on how to do this. What is the correct syntax for this, please ? Is it at all possible ?

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: Why are you not able to write it? Is there an error? How do you declare your popup? What is in the root of your popup?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

It's giving me a build error: `Error XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Resources", or mismatching type between value and property.`

IntelliSense gives a similar error: `Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'Popup'.`

I just have a Grid with some elements inside of it, declared via XAML, with the standard code-behind (partial class that calls `InitializeComponent()`).

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, can you please provide the solution, I'm facing same issue

Comment: Add Resources to parent layout. it will apply child control.
[link](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/samples/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample/Views/Popups/ButtonPopup.xaml)

**<VerticalStackLayout Style="{StaticResource PopupLayout}">
  <VerticalStackLayout.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary> **

Comment: I did notice the `<toolkit:Popup.Resources>` tag in your question is closing as a `<toolkit:Popup>`. Either way I've posted an answer that'll hopefully solve this for some of us. Adding the resources to the popup itself did not work for me, but to a child of it did work.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this, the `<toolkit:Popup>` does not have a Resources-attribute (yet). Instead you may want to use the Resources-attribute on the first child element (container) of the actual popup. In my case it was a `<frame>` element:

```
<toolkit:Popup>
    <Frame>
        <Frame.Resources>
            <model:CurrencyPickerConverter x:Key="CurrencyPickerConverter" />
        </Frame.Resources>
    </Frame>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

You can then use the converter for any controls within the `<Frame>` element.